# Google Sheets App Script Find and Replace

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do something but I'm not too code savy.
I have two sheets, one has a two columns "Status" and "ID", then  I have a second sheet that is blank. The first sheet is huge but I need a script in which I can paste a bunch of random IDs into the blank sheet then run this script and it will search the ID column of sheet 1, if any ID on Sheet 2 matches the ID on sheet 1 then change the status from "On Hold" to "Sent"

I think I'm headed in the right direction but I'm not having much luck.
Here's what I have:

```
  function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Script Menu')
      .addItem('Run Script', 'Sent')
      .addToUi();
}

function SentToOCS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("Sent IDs"); //Sheet containing IDs
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var searchData = source.getDataRange().getValues(); //The IDs we want to find
  var ids = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues(); //Data Range and values of data to search
  var status = sheet1.getDataRange(); //Data Range of "On Hold" status

  for (var j = 0; j<searchData.length; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i<ids.length; i++) {
      if (ids(i) == searchData(j)){
        status(i) == "Sent";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You definitly are in the right direction! You might wanna add a loop around this to search on all of the "searchData" values, and in the loop, to refer to the current Id you can do `Ids[i]`.

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site should be specific, so, what is your question? Ref. [tour] and [ask].

Comment: status and Ids are the same range. You haven't gotten to the values yet. Checkout getValues() in the Spreadsheet/range documentation.  Where do your randdom Ids come from?

Comment: I get and list of ID's where the task has been changed from on hold to sent, so I need a way to mass change this in my own sheet. So ideally I can copy/paste the ID's I'm given into the second sheet and in the first sheet have the status of each matched ID change to "Sent" if they match.

Comment: Sorry it is a little vague. Here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zp3PiG5z28hmCDtjNLS2AVkq-yeBMFJF46dyPryasKc/edit?usp=sharing
I thought this would be easy to do but I only  know some basics. Thank you for helping! Let me know if I can answer any more questions. Also, my original data has over 15,000 rows and that's why I'd like to automate this process so the tasks can be marked off when they are Sent but all I get is a list of the IDs that have been sent but in my sheet they are all over the place, so automating this process would save a lot of time!